# Sphinx Filter Limit of 4096

Tags: php, sphinx

Sphinx MySQL search seems to have a limit to the number of items allowed as an array for SetFilter.

I had attempted to use:

```
foreach (array_chunk($venues, 4096) as $value)
{
    $sphinx->SetFilter('venue', $value);
}
```

But upon checking, this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Any ideas how using Sphinx and the PHP library I am able to get around this limit?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at your config file values within sphinx for:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-max-filter-values

Should be able to tweak that, I may be wrong but I think the limit is sphinx having a value set rather than the PHP library.