# Filtering a large number of documents in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

In my app, users can favorite documents. Sphinx is used to allow them to search for matching documents. If a user wants to search their favorites, I first go directly to the database (mySQL) to fetch a list of document IDs and use that to filter the search in sphinx. The pseudocode looks something like this:

```
function searchFavoritesForUser($userId, $query) {
  $favoriteIds = getFavoriteIdsForUser($userId);
  $sphinx = new Sphinx(...);
  $sphinx->setFilter('document_id', $favoriteIds);
  return $sphinx->search($query);
}
```

This works fine if the user has a reasonable number of favorites. If the user has a large number of favorites, then loading the favorites can use a potentially large amount of memory and setting the filter in sphinx can run up again [various limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844737/sphinx-filter-limit-of-4096) in `searchd`.

I realize that I can adjust those config values, but it seems like there must be a better way to design this. Ideally, I would be able to eliminate the step where I have to load all of the favorite document IDs from the database into main memory.

Answer (score 1):

While you create sphinx index, you can create `MVA (multi-value attribute)` for favorites in sphinx having (doc_id, user_id) and then search directly in sphinx, no need to query to MySql.